# I'm having trouble creating a REPL using a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

**Problem**: In python construct a programming language named, Adder REPL.

The Adder language has only a few simple statements:

"**quit**" To exit the REPL or terminate a program.

"**input var**" To prompt for and allow the user to enter a value for the variable named var .

"**print val**" To print the value val .

"**var gets val**" variable var is assigned the value val .

"**var adds val**" variable var has the value val added to it.

Where:

• var is always a variable name that contains only letters; and

• val can be either:

**a variable name that contains only letters; or**

**a natural number that contains only digits.**

The Adder REPL allows the user to enter commands interactively. This exercise has a longer problem using a dictionary.

Hints: Make good use of string methods. Can you divide your program up into smaller pieces by defining functions?

**My solution so far**

I've created a simple solution using a infinite while loop but I can't seem to implement a dictionary to my program, any ideas or help will be much appreciated.

```py
def decor(func):
    def wrap():
        print("======================")
        func()
        print("======================")
    return wrap

@decor
def print_text():
    print("Welcome to Adder REPL.")
print_text()

def loop():
    while 1:
        x = input("??? ")
        if x == 'quit':
            print('Goodbye.')
            break

        try:
            y = eval(x)
            if y: print(y)
        except:
            try:
                exec(x)
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error:", e)
loop()
```

**Expected input/output**

```
Welcome to the Adder REPL.
??? a gets 1
??? input b
Enter a value for b: 2
??? c gets a
??? c adds b
??? print a
a equals 1
??? print b
b equals 2
??? print c
c equals 3
??? print z
z is undefined.
??? print 32
32
??? blerg
Syntax error.
??? 23 gets z
Syntax error.
??? quit
Goodbye.
```

Comment: Your solution is a combination of catching user commands (detecting `print` `input` etc.), storing variables key/values in a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and doing appropriate actions (`print` `add` etc). You don't need `eval` or `exec`. These are all simple tasks you should be able to do, or if you are stuck with a more specific one (e.g. implementing `input var`) we could provide a detailed throughout tutorial. Right now I think you could learn more trying by yourself with these hints

Comment: you also have not used the hint... *Make good use of string methods*...string methods are [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods). Given this is homework I won't tell you which one to use but there is one clear choice from these methods.